# WPF grouping for checkboxes

Tags: wpf, checkbox

```
    <CheckBox Content="1" Margin="43,73,430,227" />
    <CheckBox  Content="2" Margin="123,73,359,227"/>
</Grid>
```

Above are my checkboxe. I need to group them. I f check 1 then 2 should be unchecked and vice versa. This should be done in xaml.  Is there any property settings or xaml code to apply my requirement other than adding c# code.

Comment: if you need only 1 control in the group to be checked, better use `RadioButton`

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried using RadioButton?

```
 <RadioButton GroupName="MyGroup" Content="1" Margin="43,73,430,227" />
 <RadioButton GroupName="MyGroup"  Content="2" Margin="123,73,359,227"/>
```

If you still need them to look like checkboxes, use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35163278/232566).