# Checkbox in ListView - Add_Click

Tags: wpf, powershell

I have a checkbox in a listview:

```
                <ListView x:Name="listCertificate" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Margin="15,15,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="350">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="true" ColumnHeaderToolTip="InfoPaquet">
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Checked">
                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Checked}"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding NotBefore}">
                                <GridViewColumnHeader>Valid From</GridViewColumnHeader>
                            </GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding NotAfter}">
                                <GridViewColumnHeader>Valid To</GridViewColumnHeader>
                            </GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Subject}">
                                <GridViewColumnHeader>Subject</GridViewColumnHeader>
                            </GridViewColumn>
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
```

Now I would like too add the functionality that when I check one checkbox that every other checkbox will be disabled. Basically, only one checkbox can be checked at the time.

My issue is how can I get the one checkbox I click:

```
$hash.listCertificate = $hash.Window.FindName('listCertificate')
    $hash.listCertificate.Add_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown({
        param([System.Object]$sender, [System.EventArgs]$Event)
        Write-Host $Event.OriginalSource.text
        Write-Host $Event.SelectedIndex
    })

    hash.listCertificate.View.Columns[0].Add_Click({
        HandleCheckBoxChecked $_
    })
```

I tried different approaches but they are all wrong. Also I am not really sure how to know about functions like Add_Click.

Comment: Wouldn't a RadioButton be better for this?

Comment: Or a CheckBox that has its IsChecked property bound to the IsSelected property of its parent ListViewItem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```xml
  <GridViewColumn Header="Checked">
      <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
              <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding Checked}"
                           GroupName="listCertificateGroup"/>
          </DataTemplate>
      </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
  </GridViewColumn>
```

Comment: I think I have still a problem with the Radiobutton that it can be checked multiple times, which I guess is because it is inside of a gridview. So I tried adding a binding with the listview but I am missing something, or I am totally wrong:
<RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding Checked}" GroupName="{Binding DataContext.AttrName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView.View}}}"/>

Can you help me again please?

Comment: @Stephan I can help you, but more of your code is required. I will have no problem repeating the Fragments that you posted, and they will work in my implementation. So the problem is not with them. It would be better if you create a minimal example that reproduces your problem, upload it to GitHub and provide a link to this repository.

Comment: I also don’t understand this binding: GroupName="{Binding DataContext.AttrName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType= {x:Type ListView.View}}}"

Are you using many different RadioButton groups in one window?

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are just with stupid ;) In Notepad++ I collapsed the listview I wanted to work on but instead was working on a different / the wrong one.  Your solution is working perfectly. Also, I know it is not liked, I changed the style from RadioButton to CheckBox: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35163028/how-design-a-style-in-wpf-radiobutton-like-checkbox